# jquery click function conflicts

Tags: jquery

I have a problem when putting a click function inside a click function. I also tried mousedown(), but the same problem. When **else** is executed and click the button. The click function is running twice.

```
$('.tableData').click(function(){
    if($('tr.trSelected').length > 1) {
        $('.box-edit').addClass('btn-disabled');
        $('.box-info').addClass('btn-disabled');

        $('.nav-edit').unbind('click');
        $('.nav-info').unbind('click');

    }
    else {
        $('.box-edit').removeClass('btn-disabled');
        $('.box-info').removeClass('btn-disabled');

        $('.nav-edit').bind('click', function() {
            $('.sub-nav-edit').slideToggle(200);
            $('.box-edit').toggleClass('sub-nav-active');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it, to stop handling bubbling the click event , by using `stopImmediatePropagation` (of the event parameter, which I've added `e`).

```
$('.tableData').click(function(e){

    if($('tr.trSelected').length > 1) {
        $('.box-edit').addClass('btn-disabled');
        $('.box-info').addClass('btn-disabled');

        $('.nav-edit').unbind('click');
        $('.nav-info').unbind('click');

    }
    else {
        $('.box-edit').removeClass('btn-disabled');
        $('.box-info').removeClass('btn-disabled');
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $('.nav-edit').bind('click', function() {
            $('.sub-nav-edit').slideToggle(200);
            $('.box-edit').toggleClass('sub-nav-active');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put that if statement into your "click" function and test there if the button is currently selected or not. That way you don't need to unbind/rebind functions.